# PHP, jQuery Ajax and json return over a cross domain

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I have my php coded page on one server that returns a json result.
  php file called: getInfoData.php and the return is as below.

```
  echo json_encode($v);
```

No I can use $.getJSON(??) to read the json and run it all on the same sever fine, but I need the php page to be on a different sever than the js page calling it.

But then I get then when I do I get the cross domain issue.

So I changed the code to use the following (jsonp):

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'FILE_LOCATION_ON_ANOTHER_SERVER',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { console.log("Success"); },
    error: function() {console.log('Failed!'); }
});
```

but I do not see anything I just get the following with my console:

```
  http://www.THEURL.com/FOLDER/FILENAME.php?callback=jQuery171013088115444406867_1332256223342&_=1332256223343
```

and a message saying failed!.

What am I doing wrong and how if at all can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP isn't actually JSON.  It's a bit of a "hack".  JSONP is actually a JavaScript file, that gets downloaded and ran.

In your PHP page, you should be passed a `callback` parameter.  You need to "wrap" your JSON in it.  It should look like this:

```
func({json: data})
```

So, your PHP should look like this:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($v) . ')';
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this usually but maybe there is a better way

```
<?php header('content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['callback']) . '('.json_encode($data).')';
```

since i saw you provided a callback parameter everything should be ok

Comment: JSONP isn't actually JSON, it's JavaScript file that gets added to a script tag.  You should use the `application/javascript` MIME instead.

Comment: @Rocket thaks for the suggestion :)